# How to make a 3D model of a bundle of fibers of an organic shape

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I'm wanting to make a bundle of fibers to along an organic shape (so not a cylinder). I have the 3D model of the shape (an approximation of a muscle), and I want the fibers aligned to the longest axis. Here is a picture of the model:

[image: Muscle]

So far I've done the trick of selecting all the vertices, doing the 'Checker Deselect' function, separating out the selected vertices, turning those vertices into a curve, and then going to the Object Data Properties for the curve and changing the bevel size from 0 to a nonzero number.

[image]

The result is cool but I need the fibers to only run the longest length of the muscle. Is there a function that I'm missing that can get rid of the crossbars?

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe you could get rid of the horizontal edge loops?

Answer (score 0):

Automating the process a little:  This geometry nodes set up deletes rings and makes the vertical loops into tubes.

[image]

Here is the same object duplicated with and without this GN modifier. (It also has a subdivision modifier with a value of 2.)

[image]

There are problems, it works better the closer the object is to a cylinder, as you noted.
The node starts to break if you move vertices on a horizontal edge loop in the Z direction.

Comment: This was helpful. This node modification seemed to work well with cylinder derived objects, but broke when they became more non cylindrical. I think it wasn't working when it wasn't able to identify the long dimension? Or something? What happened was that the small triangles that are randomly laid out in XYZ have the fibril structure, so I created a wireframe looking thing but doesn't have any directionality. If you have any direction from there, it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Even with this you can get some uneven shapes, just by moving vertices along X and Y.   But that is the best I have at the moment.  (Maybe you will get additional answers.  Something using texture or displacement is also worth researching.)